# How to do bulk query operations on Cosmos DB using gremlin API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We want to perform bulk (millions of low-cost) query/read operations on a graph that we have in Cosmos DB using the Gremlin API in .NET C#. What is the best way to do so?

We know about BulkExecutor Library which only supports Bulk Import and Bulk Update operations. Is there something similar for Bulk Query/Read operations?

Currently, I am using a Gremlin.Net.Driver, GremlinClient (`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet`)  to fire queries. However, this driver is very slow compared to the BulkExecutor libraries BulkImport operations.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only support using Bulk is using [Bulk V3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/) for point read operations (not queries).

So if you know the Id and Partition key value of your documents, you can leverage Bulk mode with `ReadItem` operations.